# Android dependency not working

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I'm trying to use the [binance Java API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api). When I add:

```
Implementation: 'com. binance.api: binance-api-client: 1.0.0'
```

to the dependendencies and sync it, I get an error saying

> Failed to resolve: com.binance.api:binance-api-client:1.0.0

I also tried the following:

```
Implementation: 'com. binance.api: binance-api-client:+'
```

which didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the github owner [didn't create a maven release yet](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/issues/23). So, you need to depends on **jitpack.io**.

Modify your root build.gradle to contains maven jitpack.io like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

then add the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.binance-exchange:binance-java-api:69f56f5fcf'
```

You can take a look at https://jitpack.io/#binance-exchange/binance-java-api